# Input not related to the Model in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model called Event that has many Videos. Like this:

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
    include EmbedableVideo
    belongs_to :event
    before_save :set_embed_link!
end
```

And:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :title, use: :slugged

  has_many :photos
  has_many :videos
```

To simplify my view, I will put one input on the Events page. This input will receive the videos url separated with a ";" between each url.

http://youtube.com/dasdasd; http://youtube.com/123dasdas ;

In my controller, I will split this input and create a Video for each entry.

How can I read this data from my view? Because, this input its not directly on my model when saving?

Thanks

Comment: _"How can I read this data from my view?"_ – your view, i.e. the browser submitting the form, will pass the data to your controller. You can read it via [`params`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#parameters)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. But I don't agree with using csv style attributes makes it easier on the user. Why not use `accepts_nested_attributes` and use a gem like https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form. It is much more extendable than you current solution.

Answer (score 0):

let's say you have the form with an input with the name of "videos", when you do submit, the input value comes in params[:videos] for example, then you can do something like

```
params[:videos].split(";").each do |video|
  Video.create(url: video)
end
```